# How do I connect to Google Vision using client libraries? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-vision

I am trying to send an image to the Google Vision API using Node.js by following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries

I have installed the client libraries.  Then I created a Service Account key and explicitly set the value of the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the JSON file that was downloaded on creation of the Service Account key.

However when I run the following Node.js code:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

// Performs label detection on the image file
client
  .labelDetection('./Driver_license.jpg')
  .then(results => {
    const labels = results[0].labelAnnotations;

    console.log('Labels:');
    labels.forEach(label => console.log(label.description));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

I receive the following 2 errors in the console:

> (node:22585) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead
>
> Auth error:Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

The second error about the Auth error continues to print out over and over again until I terminate execution.

I have followed the Google Cloud tutorials closely so I'm not sure why this isn't working.  Have I missed a step in Authentication?

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/issues/120

Comment: Are you still experiencign the issue? There is a progress on [it](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-nodejs/issues/286) but the fix for long running operations is still in progress.